# Why twitter oauth not returning oauth_verifier?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

My application use twitter sdk to send some tweet, but sometimes I sign in twitter, the return URL without oauth_verifier, it's only a callback_url.

I find some body have a same problem as mine, this is a link

[A same problem](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/7771)

but I can't find solution, are there some body can help me? Thanks.

Comment: can you post your code..

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]** The Twitter instructions are not CLEAR! To return oauth_verifier with the callback url, just **fill the Callback URL field** ("not required") at `https://apps.twitter.com/app/<id_of_app>/settings`

**[RESOLVIDO]** A documentação do Twitter não está clara! Para retornar o oauth_verifier como querystring da url de callback, basta **preencher o campo Callback URL** ("não obrigatório") em `https://apps.twitter.com/app/<id_of_app>/settings`